# Probability that one random graph is contained in another

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G_{n,p}, n\in \mathbb{N}, p\in(0,1)$ be the binomial random graph, i.e. a graph on $n$ vertices where an edge is in $G_{n,p}$ with probability $p$.

For some $q\in(0,1)$, what is the probability that $G_{n,p}\subset G_{n,q}$?

Comment: For $n = 3$, the probability is $q^3 + 3q^2(1-q)(1-p^3) + 3q(1-q)^2((1-p)^3 + 3p(1-p)^2)$ where term 1 is when $G(n,q)$ is $K_3$, term 2 is when $G(n,q)$ is $P_3$ and term 3 is when $G(n,q)$ is $P_2$. In short, it's probably intractable in general, but I'd like to see the asymptotics. As an aside, if you take $n = \infty$, they are isomorphic: http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7544

Comment: Are $G(n,p)$ and $G(n,q)$ independent, here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the two graphs are independent of each other, we could do the following, where $N:=\binom{n}{2}$:$\newcommand{\order}[1]{\lvert #1\rvert}$

Start by partition the set of all graphs on $[n]$ based on the number of edges they contain; let $\mathcal{G}_{n,k}$ be the set of such graphs on $[n]$ with $k$ edges. Then we get
$$
\begin{align*}
P(G_{n,p}\subseteq G_{n,q})=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sum_{G\in \mathcal{G}_{n,k}}P(G_{n,p}=G,\ G_{n,p}\subseteq G_{n,q})=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sum_{G\in \mathcal{G}_{n,k}}P(G_{n,p}=G,\ G\subseteq G_{n,q}).
\end{align*}
$$
Now, of course these events are independent, and so we can break up the probability. Further, if $G$ contains $k$ edges, then $P(G_{n,p}=G)=p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$ and $P(G\subseteq G_{n,q})=q^k$. Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
P(G_{n,p}\subseteq G_{n,q})&=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sum_{G\in \mathcal{G}_{n,k}}P(G_{n,p}=G)P(G\subseteq G_{n,q})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sum_{G\in \mathcal{G}_{n,k}}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}q^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}(pq)^k(1-p)^{N-k}\\
&=(1-p+pq)^N.
\end{align*}
$$
Note that this is definitely in $[0,1]$: writing the base as $1-(p-pq)=1-p(1-q)$ shows this.

---

Another way to come to this:

The event that $G_{n,p}\subseteq G_{n,q}$ is precisely the event that each edge is either not contained in $G_{n,p}$ or is contained in both $G_{n,p}$ and $G_{n,q}$. These are disjoint events, and the events that this holds for each edge are independent of each other.

For a given edge $e$, the probability of this is
$$
P(e\notin G_{n,p}\text{ or }e\in G_{n,p}\text{ and }G_{n,q})=(1-p) + pq.
$$
Noting that there are $N$ such edges, we again get
$$
P(G_{n,p}\subseteq G_{n,q})=(1-p+pq)^N.
$$

Comment: This decomposition is not needed (or rather, others exist, which make for a simpler argument) but the result is true.

Comment: That's certainly the case; however, I find that these sort of decomposition arguments are an invaluable thing for people new to the field to see.

Comment: @Did I assume you like this one a bit better?

Comment: +1. Here is yet another one: call $\varepsilon(G_p)$ the number of edges in $G_p$, then $\varepsilon(G_p)$ is binomial $(N,p)$ and $P(G_p\subseteq G_q\mid G_p)=q^{\varepsilon(G_p)}$. QED.